# crystal report ask for log in info?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, dataset

i have crystal report dynamic `datasource`  i am using `dataset` to design it only 
when report load ask for login info with Server name my `dataset` name not my server name 
here is my code

```
TechTouch_Point.Reports.Invoice cryRpt = new Reports.Invoice();
string n = ((BillNumbertoshow)Owner).billnum;
service.BillViewService bvs = new service.BillViewService();
db.BillView bv = new db.BillView();
List<db.BillView> billlist = new List<db.BillView>();
billlist = bvs.GetPaged("InvNo="+n, null, 0, 10000, out x).ToList();
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
cryRpt.SetDataSource(billlist);
```

i am sure about list get right data

[image]

Comment: i know the problem 
i define report data source as (dataset) and try to send (List) For It :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you Make your report Datasource = dataset 
and send it List